# When fetching data from API I get this error: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: r, dataframe, api, httr, jsonlite

Using R to fetch some data from the US Census Bureau, but cannot find a solution. This code was working yesterday and is very simple, but I can't find a solution, it always returns the following error.

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Failure when receiving data from the peer

This is the code that was used, however, getting data from any api does not seem to be working:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

res = GET("api.census.gov/data/2021/acs/acs1/subject?get=NAME,group(S2408)&for=us:1&key=1c8d16edd6d5c9c7dfa9027309dd6bd95802d614")
```

Comment: If I run the code you provided I don't get any errors. Are you sure your network isn't blocking the calls? Were you making a lot of calls to the API?

Comment: How would I know if the network is blocking the calls?

Comment: Can you access the URL from your browser? That's at least one way to check.